# transaction processing scenario simulation in a web application

Tags: testing, web-applications, transactions

I am looking into transaction processing and I cannot find a way to simulate **multiple** queries (HTTP Methods) to a resource (script) which will act on shared data.

e.g an HTTP GET representing access to a resource from user1 with param1 and another HTTP GET for access from user2 with param2

For example 2 users trying to book a limited resource "at the same time" or access a url which triggers actions that should have all ACID properties.

Is there a way to test such scenarios in a web application?

Should I stick in a "programmable" scenario (a scenario I will code) which can run using a stress test tool ?

What method(s) do you use in such cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) to set up test scripts which run multiple simulated users, varying test content and so on. You can even run slaves to test from more than one physical test clients if you need to increase your load. The requests can be created with templates including user-specific data, pick random prepared requests or run scripts to create the data for each request.